# Why does the SoundCloud API seem crippled?

Tags: javascript, soundcloud

I'm building an app, and trying to use API /tracks using the 'q' filter. This queries SoundCloud and retrieves songs based on search terms. Simple enough.

My problem: it seems like the search functionality is crippled using /tracks when compared to the search feature found on soundcloud.com itself.

The results seem to be much lower quality via the API, whereas searching directly on the website returns high-quality results.

Could a SoundCloud engineer comment on this?

Comment: Isn't this a question for the soundcloud people instead of Stack Overflow?

Comment: @PeeHaa SoundCloud is actually using SO for their developer support. They even list topics tagged with `soundcloud` on their developer site. http://developers.soundcloud.com/support

Comment: Yes I know that they have started doing that last year. Are they also committed to answer questions on here or are they simply going [the facebook route](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121547/is-it-time-to-re-evaluate-the-facebook-stack-overflow-partnership).

Comment: Search via api certainly does seem poor. I think they focus on Soundcloud being a discovery platform, not a general purpose one.

Comment: @PeeHaa they don't provide any support outside of StackOverflow. That's why I'm asking here. All is quiet on the SoundCloud front...

Comment: pls. share some code. this could be helpful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19896943/soundcloud-filtering-by-query-on-the-tracks-of-a-specific-user-doesnt-work

Comment: i've never used the API, but when searching on the site, does it maybe return results that are more relevant to your listening habits / user profile? as opposed to an "anonymous" search via the API? the results maybe low quality to you, but high quality to others.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using 'q' paramaeter and not 'query'.

`SC.get('/tracks', {q:"keyword"}, function(tracks) {
  console.log(tracks)
})`

Comment: Yea, that's what I use. Their API is crippled.

Comment: I'm not going to mark the answer "correct." Your answer doesn't fix the problem.