# SoundCloud, filtering by query on the tracks of a specific user doesn't work

Tags: json, soundcloud

I'm trying to use the soundcloud api to get the tracks of a specific user that's matching the query i am inputting

here's an example without querying, works fine, gets all tracks for that user
http://api.soundcloud.com/users/4493849/tracks.json?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID

works fine and gets me the 5 tracks for that user

now I need to only get the track called "Test Audio". so I do as follows
http://api.soundcloud.com/users/4493849/tracks.json?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&q=Test

now the problem is, when I put the q= , it simply brings me all tracks in the whole of soundcloud which match Test, i.e. it queries all soundcloud not the 5 tracks for that user as I want to

Any help please

Comment: You're right, it does appear to be broken. Their [API docs for /users](http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#users) does indicate that it supports the `q` filter parameter, but I can confirm that including it doesn't work as documented.

Comment: what should we do now ? How do we report this error to them ?

Comment: still didn't get any useful info

Comment: can I ask from where did you get the soundcloud api or sdk? I also want to develop something that uses soundcloud :) thanks

Comment: http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs

Answer (score 0):

I tried it with the SC own SDK here:

http://jsfiddle.net/iambnz/H7VW8/

```
SC.initialize({ client_id: "cd3e093bf9688f09e3cdf15565fed8f3" });  

SC.get('/users/4493849', { q: 'test' }, function(tracks) {
  console.log(tracks);
});
```

Result will be just one track / object:

```
Object {id: 4493849, kind: "user", permalink: "the-uprising-developers", username: "The Uprising Developers", uri: "http://api.soundcloud.com/users/4493849"…}
```

Comment: That's not what I'm asking for. Your request is returning the user, and it will disregard the keyword anyway, try removing the test keyword query and see what happens, nothing changed, because it still gets u the same user. I wish to retrieve the tracks not the users. The result object in your answer says it clearly, the kind is "user", I want the kind to be track

Comment: Oupps, i see. I hope i get back to you, but as it looks now, its broken.

Comment: Well, you can use the user-endpoint to retrieve trackobjects. But i played around a bit and it looks like (as you said) that everything which is used in conjunction with the q-parameter will end up with wrong responses. http://jsfiddle.net/iambnz/g93FY/ (you will get all my tracks - if you add the q parameter, it will scrap the results)

Comment: for the time being I'm retrieving all tracks for the user and then doing the querying manually in the client application, but obviously it will be tons much more efficient if it was done on the cloud

Answer (score 0):

The SoundCloud's API doesn't work with user sub-resources and search query.

So, the best way to do this is to load all tracks (batch load with offset parameter, if user has lots of tracks) all tracks and then code your search in the results.

This was the first feature that i needed too when i started my app, but there is no way to do this only with thiers API.

Comment: I think the problem is that [their API docs](http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#users) specifically state that the `q` filter parameter should work with users' resources. Under the **/users** headline you'll see: Example, Properties, Subresources, and **Filters**.

Comment: ah, their API is so obsolete, and it's not updated for more than 2 years. for example, it still says that sets (playlists) can be created by your own tracks, but actually, it works with other tracks too.

if you want to use SoundCloud resources, go to soundcloud.com, open dev tools and start tracking the requests.